# Why does my child love loud (scary) noises?

Tags: noise

My child is 1½ years, and has always liked loud noises that cause other children to cry. I started noticing it when there was a bang and 2 other babies present cried and she clapped and smiled.
Iv noticed since that loud sounds make her laugh hysterically or clap whilst giggling. Sounds like...

- visiting my parents, my dad was building in the garden and was using a staple gun. I started moving away distracting her incase it scared her but instead she wanted to get closer and laughed hysterically each time it went off.
- popping balloons also make her laugh
- the tv was turnt up super high (unintentionally) so when we switch it on instead of jumping she sat laughing.

I can only find things online about over sensitive reactions to noise with nothing about loving loud noises.

Is this normal???

Comment: It seems normal for your child, which is nice. :)

Comment: I wish I had been this baby.  I was and am overly startled by noises.

Comment: Is her hearing otherwise ok? Does she react properly to soft sounds ?

Comment: {Suddenly} scary loud noise happens he starts clap or whilst giggling. is this the question?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have reason to believe they have poor hearing, it does seem perfectly normal. Some children really dislike loud noises when young and some love them.

My youngest wasn't keen on any sudden or loud noise for a few years, but my eldest has always loved them.

We have tried to identify any reason why our kids are so different, and the only thing we can point to related to sound volume (that is probably just coincidental) are attending some very loud air shows in the days before the birth of my eldest, and then some firework shows in the first couple of weeks of his life.